# Can OO Presentation go full-screen to the secondary monitor?

Tags: 10.10, nvidia, multiple-monitors, openoffice.org

I have two screens set up on my desktop, the second is a projector. For obvious reasons I would like to have the secondary screen ( projector) display the full-screen view of OO Presentation.

I am using an NVIDIA Graphics card and the NVIDIA X Server settings.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

Go to `Slide Show` -> `Slide Show Settings...` and select the desired display as your `Presentation display`.

[image]

Now if you start your presentation using <kbd>F5</kbd> it will be displayed on the selected display.

The same applies for LibreOffice.